# Using grep to find matching patterns within files in different directories via perl

Tags: perl, grep

Im modifying an existing perl script which checks the status of some tests ran by going to their directory and parsing for pass, fail, or incomplete. I want to extend this script to generate a sublist containing the incompleted tests based on 3 strings:

```
"Error: Failure to checkout svverification license feature." 
"Error: Unable to checkout verification license - required for testbench features" 
"FATAL ERROR: License connection lost and unable to reconnect after multiple attempts."
```

Each test name has its own directory and inside the directory is a log file named `vsim.log`. I could do this directory with a `grep`, but I figured it would be nice to implement it into the script so I dont have to manually `grep` every time there are incompletes.

The script has a variable `$cur_test_name` which I was going to use to perform this since I have to make sure to go into the proper sub-directory.

```
chdir("/testout/$cur_test_name.1/") or die "Cannot chdir to /testout/$cur_test_name.t";
if(system(grep -f "Error: Failure to checkout svverification license feature." vsim.log) or 
system(grep -f "Error: Unable to checkout verification license - required for testbench features" vsim.log) or 
system(grep -f "# FATAL ERROR: License connection lost and unable to reconnect after multiple attempts." vsim.log))
{
   open($incomplete_tests, '>'; 'incompletes.lst') or die "Cannot open file $!in write mode";
   print {$incomplete_tests} $cur_Test_name . "\n";    
   close $incomplete_tests;
}
 chdir("../../") or die "Cannot chdir to ../../";
```

So basically, I want to change directory to the subdirectory and check inside the vsim.log file of those patterns exist. If they create a new file via open (I think this is how its done?) and write the test name variable into the file. Then i close the file, and go back to the top level directory and repeat this for each test that is incomplete.

But this does not compile and Im new to perl so im having trouble figuring out how to use `system()` properly. I've seen different formats and I've seen some solutions using only `grep` without `system` so Im kind of stuck.

The errors i get are the following:

```
Bareword found where operator expected at bin/run_regress.pl line 1279, near ""Error: Failure to checkout svverification license feature." vsim"
        (Missing operator before vsim?)
Bareword found where operator expected at bin/run_regress.pl line 1279, near ""Error: Unable to checkout verification license - required for testbench features" vsim"
        (Missing operator before vsim?)
Bareword found where operator expected at bin/run_regress.pl line 1279, near ""# FATAL ERROR: License connection lost and unable to reconnect after multiple attempts." vsim"
        (Missing operator before vsim?)
Not enough arguments for grep at bin/run_regress.pl line 1279, near ""Error: Failure to checkout svverification license feature." vsim"
syntax error at bin/run_regress.pl line 1279, near ""Error: Failure to checkout svverification license feature." vsim"
Global symbol "$cur_Test_name" requires explicit package name at bin/run_regress.pl line 1282.
syntax error at bin/run_regress.pl line 1287, near "}"
```

**EDIT:**

The place where I want to place my code is in the following part of the script:

```
for(my $j=0;$j<$number_of_bfm_based_smoke_100pin_tests;$j++)
{
    chdir("../rtl_mcu_bfm_qfn_100/") or die "Cannot chdir to ../rtl_mcu_bfm_qfn_100";
    $curr_test_name = $bfm_based_smoke_100pin_tests[$j] ;
    process_test_name($curr_test_name);
    check_status($sim_process_out[1],$bfm_based_smoke_100pin_tests[$j],$seed,"BFM");
    $sr_nu++;
    chdir($start_dir);
}
```

and the `check_status` subroutine is

```
sub check_status
{
   my ( $pass_fail_string,$cur_test_name,$seed_val,$xdata_mstr) = @_;
   if ($pass_fail_string =~ /Test FAILED! Test did not end properly/)
   {
       # ===== THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO PLACE MY CODE ===== #
       $incomplete_cnt++ ;
       printf (STORE_REGRESS_RSLT "|%9d|%78s|%7d|%11s|%12s|\n",$sr_nu,$cur_test_name,$seed_val,"-",$xdata_mstr);
   }
   elsif ($pass_fail_string =~ /Test PASSED/)
   {
       $pass_cnt++; 
       printf (STORE_REGRESS_RSLT "|%9d|%78s|%7d|%11s|%12s|\n",$sr_nu,$cur_test_name,$seed_val,"PASSED",$xdata_mstr);
   }
   elsif ($pass_fail_string =~ /Test FAILED/)
   {
       $fail_cnt++; 
       printf (STORE_REGRESS_RSLT "|%9d|%78s|%7d|%11s|%12s|\n",$sr_nu,$cur_test_name,$seed_val,"FAILED",$xdata_mstr);
   }
   else
   {
       $incomplete_cnt++ ;
       printf (STORE_REGRESS_RSLT "|%9d|%78s|%7d|%11s|%12s|\n",$sr_nu,$cur_test_name,$seed_val,"-",$xdata_mstr);
   }
}
```

Comment: Perl grep is not system grep. You have to open the file and search for the line you are looking for. If you want to use system grep, why not use bash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, there is no reason to go out to the system in order to search files for patterns; process files.

Next, if you *were* to do it `system` is a wrong tool. For one, it doesn't return the command's `STDOUT` but rather the exit status (`$?`). Here you only need to know *whether* there were matches and `grep` exit does convey this, and is packaged into the high bits of [$?](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#$?). Thanks to [ysth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17389/ysth) for a comment.

However, your code still won't see errors since any non-zero return is true under `if`. You'd need to analyze `$?`, and if `$? >> 8 == 0` that means that there were matches, according to `grep`'s man page.  But then the utility of this approach is limited to `grep`.

Also, if the design ever changed and you need the output (lines that match for example ), you'd want `qx` (backticks), or one of a number of other tools/modules. Just do it all in Perl instead.

Here is a working program along the lines of what you want

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';
use Cwd;

my @dirs = qw(one two three);   # my tests, change to suitable names
my $logfile = 'log.txt';    
my $incomplete_tests = 'incomplete_tests.log';
my $curr_test_name   = 'current_test';

# regex to search with  
my $err_qr = qr/Error: Failure|Error: Unable|FATAL ERROR:/;  #/

# Open log file for append
open my $fh_incomp, '>>', $incomplete_tests 
    or die "Can't open to append $incomplete_tests: $!";

my $orig_dir = cwd;
foreach my $dir (@dirs)
{
    chdir $dir or die "Can't chdir to $dir: $!";
    my $updated_name = $curr_test_name . "_$dir";  # update as/if needed

    open my $fh, '<', $logfile  or do {
        warn "Can't open $logfile: $!";
        next;
    };

    while (<$fh>) {
        say $fh_incomp $updated_name if /$err_qr/;
    }   

    chdir $orig_dir or die "Can't chdir to $orig_dir: $!";
}
close $fh_incomp;
```

Since I don't understand your full problem this is basic, and with a few guesses.  It goes through a list of directories, checking a log file with the same name in each and recording the "test name" each time a line matches the regex composed ahead of time with [qr operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators).

You can change it to record error-lines as well (add a print), or to record the test name only once per log file (skip to `next` directory once it matches).

Also note that there is no reason really for `chdir`, as you can easily use `$dir` to form proper paths.  I use it in case your real code does more work and can actually benefit from being in `$dir`.

There are other ways to do this, in the first place by searching for the log-file across all directories and running the same code in each case. This can be done nicely with [File::Find::Rule](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Find::Rule) or [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny).

Comment: But grep's status tells you if it matched

Comment: Just a follow up, you have `my @dirs = qw(one two three); ` and you say to change it to suitable names, but in my case, there's over a hundred (and in some instances thousands) of test names. How would I implement it in that case?

Comment: @Javia1492  Thank you for the attribution.  Now, that follow up is the part that is unclear to me, what I refer to. From what I gather, you have some directories (`@dirs` in my example), and then you also have some "test names," but which aren't explained.  I guessed that they are related to directory names in some way, and as an example I append `_$dir` to a fixed string.  How are these names related to directories? Or is that simply a bunch of tests that you run for each directory (with unrelated names)? Can you explain this?

Comment: @zdim The relationship is that I have some top level directory **testout** which contains subdirectories with the naming convention _testname.1_. Inside this directory are a bunch of files, one of which is the **vsim.log** file which i want to parse. Each subdirectory contains this log file, which contains info related to that test. So the big picture is something like _testout/mytestname.1/vsim.log_. From what this script already contains, it seems the current working directory is _testout_.

Comment: @Javia1492  OK. Then you can first do `chdir "testout";` for instance. Then obtain the list of directories, say by `my @dirs = grep { -d && /\.\d+$/ } glob "*";` (all directories ending with `.number`) or some such.  Then for each dir form the "test name" by stripping the extension.  I take it that a dir `testname.N` corresponds to `testname` to be entered in `incomplete_tests`.  Did I get your setup right? (All of this even fits right in this little script here.)

Comment: @zdim Yea, that's pretty much it. The only unknown is whether I need to chdir to testout or not but that's something I need to determine myself based on what the current script contains.

Comment: I should add that the place in the script I want to add the code is in a subroutine which is being called inside a `for` loop. It seems that it will loop based on the number of expected tests in the folder and call the `check_status` subroutine which is passed a `$cur_test_name` and a `$pass_fail_string` which will either be `Test FAILED`, `Test PASSED`, or `Test FAILED! Test did not end properly`. The default case is just incompletes.

Comment: Alright. [_This is a response to the message previous to your last one, which I just see._]  I'll adjust the script above to this.  As for `chdir`-ing: you can form the full names to the directories and use that.  Or you can `chdir "testout";` and then get the list.  With a list of directories you can `chdir` to each, as you asked and this script does.  Or, you can just use full paths for everything.  That is a matter of what else is done, and indeed a matter of choice.

Comment: @zdim Was the script adjusted?

Comment: @Javia1492  I am just back at it now.  Your last edit threw me for the loop -- I appreciate that you show detail but it's hard to see what the code does overall.  I'll first adjust to what we talked about above, before that edit.